# Unable to click on Material UI Select using WebdriverIO

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, material-ui, ui-automation, webdriver-io

I want to know if there is any way to click on a hidden element using Webdriverio

One of the components used in our project is `material-ui select`. I can see that it is `hidden` when rendered on the page, like below. When I click on it using `browser.click('#fileName')` in javascript, I am getting an error message as `element not visible`.

[image]

Just wanted to check if there is any way to click on this hidden element from Webdriverio. Our developers are currently looking into implementing native select if I couldn't find anyway to get it working.

Writing it here to see if anyone else faced this problem and has worked around it, if yes, can you please share with me about how you overcome this?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit1:**

Image of the ui
[image]

Comment: Why do you want to click on a hidden element? Typically a hidden element isn't going to have a click event handler.

Comment: I need to select a value from the dropdown, I am not sure why it's hidden though

Comment: That is not a drop down.

Comment: Please check the question, I have added the UI for this now. It looks like a dropdown to me.

Comment: If you want to get the file or files of an input for uploading to the server I'm guessing... you can do something like document.getElementById('fileName').files; Then you iterate those and try clicking one, but I'm not really sure what it is you want to accomplish.

Comment: I am sorry if I was not clear, I want to click on the dropdown and select a value. In this case File1 or File 2.

Comment: It looks like you may want to click on the div element above the hidden input in your example. So you could do querySelector('.jss290.jss291.jss302').click(); Which in turn should make those file elements visible.

Comment: ok let me try that